# ConnectionClosedError(None, Close(code=1011, reason='keepalive ping timeout')

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to convert speech to text with [Deepgram](https://deepgram.com/) API. Based on this [tutorial](https://blog.deepgram.com/live-transcription-fastapi/).
Here is my backend code:

```
@router.websocket('/socket')
async def speech_to_text_websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    try:
        deepgram_socket = await process_audio(websocket) 
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            deepgram_socket.send(data)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Could not process audio: {e}')
    finally:
        await websocket.close()

async def process_audio(fast_socket: WebSocket):
    async def get_transcript(data: Dict) -> None:
        if 'channel' in data:
            transcript = data['channel']['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    
            if transcript:
                await fast_socket.send_text(transcript)

    deepgram_socket = await connect_to_deepgram(get_transcript)

    return deepgram_socket

async def connect_to_deepgram(transcript_received_handler: Callable[[Dict], None]):
    dg_client = Deepgram(os.getenv('DEEPGRAM_API_KEY'))
    options = {'punctuate': True, 'interim_results': False}

    try:
        socket = await dg_client.transcription.live(options)
        socket.registerHandler(socket.event.CLOSE, lambda c: print(f'Connection closed with code {c}.'))
        socket.registerHandler(socket.event.TRANSCRIPT_RECEIVED, transcript_received_handler)
    
        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Could not open socket: {e}')
```

It works for 5 sec but then I get the below error:
[image]

Is it a problem with my backend or this is about Deepgram? How can solve this?